# Android Studio Debugger - missing platforms in "alternative source" popup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm debugging an app using Android Studio debugger. I stepped into some system classes and got the common "Source code does not match the bytecode" message. A "alternative source available for class..." bar also appeared. There's a spinner allowing me to select the sources to use with the debugger.

The only choice I have is between Android API 25 and 26 platforms, despite the fact that I have also downloaded and installed sources for other API levels. I'd like to preview the sources for API 22.

Android API 25 and 26 platforms are the only Android sources listed under the "External Libraries" section in the Project sidebar.

I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to find a workaround for this problem. To get the desired Android sources to be available for preview in the debugger:

1. Start a debug session normally
2. While the debugger is running change `compileSdkVersion` in build.gradle to the chosen API level
3. Start Gradle sync. The sync will probably fail and it's OK.
4. The chosen API platform sources will appear in "External Libraries" and should be now available for preview in the debugger.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for that. But it's unbelievable to me that this is the only way for AndroidStudio to allow me to link different Android SDK sources to a particular debug session.

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer... This definitely sounds like a hack, but there isn't a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for me was loading the Android gradle project in Intellij.  Going to the project settings > platform settings > SDKs > select the sdk version.  Remove the sources for rt.jar then add the platform sources for the android sdk version to rt.jar.  (sdk/sources/platform-xx).  Not perfect but working form my purposes.